# VSCode Code Spell Checker extension - Include TXT files

Tags: visual-studio-code, spell-checking

I'm using the VSCode Code Spell Checker, and I wish to detect typos in TXT files. But the issue is, that I want to detect it on TXT files that are being ignored for search by the VSCode.

Here is my settings.js file:

```
{
    "cSpell.words": [
        "BING",
        "DOGPILE"
    ],
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/.vscode": true,
        "**/dist": true,
        "**/misc": true,
        "**/misc/documents": true,
        "**/misc/": true,
        "/misc/": true,
        "misc/**": true,
        "**/misc/**": true,
        "**/misc/documents/**": true,
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/sources": true
    },
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript"
    ],
    "http.proxy": "",
    "http.proxyAuthorization": null,
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "none"
}
```

The file that I want to detect typo located inside the `misc` directory, that is declared in the `"search.exclude"` list (I don't want search results from any files in this directory), but **I DO WANT** to detect typos on theses files.

If I remove all of theses and the settings.js looks like that:

```
    {
    "cSpell.words": [
        "BING",
        "DOGPILE"
    ],
    "search.exclude": { },
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript"
    ],
    "http.proxy": "",
    "http.proxyAuthorization": null,
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "none"
}
```

The TXT file typo detection works, but I get the search results that include files inside the `misc` directory, which is **NOT** what I want.

Has anyone faced this issue before and know how to solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as it is explicitly stated in [Spell Checker FAQ](https://github.com/streetsidesoftware/vscode-spell-checker/blob/master/packages/client/FAQ.md)

#### *What files are excluded by the spell checker?*

> By default the spell checker excludes the same files excluded by the VS Code *search.exclude* setting.  See discussion: [#16](https://github.com/streetsidesoftware/vscode-spell-checker/issues/16), [#55](https://github.com/streetsidesoftware/vscode-spell-checker/issues/55) and [#95](https://github.com/streetsidesoftware/vscode-spell-checker/issues/95)

the correct way to address the problem exposed in the question I would say is to open an issue to the project for a new feature request to allow to override this default behavoir.

as a last resort if you absolutely need to prevent *search.exclude* from being added to the exclusions you could try to force the code installed on your machine and after restarting vscode you will have the spell check working also in those paths.

**DISCLAIMER please note what is illustrated below is a discouraged hack mentioned in here for informational purposes only, obviously if you try this kind of workaround you must be extremely aware of what you are doing**

for example:
assuming the extension was installed in `~/.vscode/extensions/streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker-1.10.2`

in the source `server/config/documentSettings.js` there is the function `async fetchSettingsFromVSCode(uri)` where it is added :

`ignorePaths: ignorePaths.concat(CSpell.ExclusionHelper.extractGlobsFromExcludeFilesGlobMap(exclude)),`

by changing in to
`ignorePaths: ignorePaths`

[image]

then quit fron `vscode` and when re-open it the extension no longer excludes the same files excluded by the VS Code *search.exclude* setting.